# BufferAsyncSink is serializing the stream

Tags: project-reactor

I am using Flux.create() to bridge from listener type API (custom HTTP server) to Flux stream. Very simple code, basically:

```
Flux.create(listener::setSink, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER)
                    ... bunch of operators
                    .subscribe();
```

And inside listener:

```
sink.next(item);
```

Everything is working fine, but after some troubleshooting I found out that BufferAsyncSink that is created by FluxCreate (for BUFFER strategy) is basically serializing downstream processing.

```
        @Override
        public FluxSink<T> next(T t) {
            queue.offer(t);
            drain();
            return this;
        }
```

This adds item to the queue, and then proceeds to drain the queue.
However, this code only allows single thread to drain the queue.

```
        void drain() {
            if (WIP.getAndIncrement(this) != 0) {
                return;
            }
```

I don't understand why is this limitation is here. Why can't multiple threads drain the queue? In fact, why is the queue even needed? 
I know I can offload next item to another thread pool with publishOn/subscribeOn, but we already have a thread pool for our HTTP server and it would be more optimal if thread that received HTTP request would continue processing flux until its down. We have backpressure built into our HTTP server so we don't need Flux to handle it. 
I looked all over Reactor documentation and can't find another way to create Flux that would not serialize the stream.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: may be you can try changing OverflowStrategy ? In your use - IGNORE makes sense . Check this para in documentation - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create . Look for keyword ' OverflowStrategy'

Comment: Thank you. I tried FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.IGNORE, but that is still wrapped with SerializedSink in Flux.create ```createMode == CreateMode.PUSH_PULL ? new SerializedSink<>(sink) :
       sink);``` I then switched to Flux.push instead  and that does seem to be doing what we need, however it comes with a stern warning that it should be used with a single thread producer.